# Can we understand SVM without knowledge of Machine Learning

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, data-mining

I was told by my adviser (future one) to look into [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) library or any other and try to get familiar with it.. to work on a programming project (on Machine Learning) (will start in a month).

my background: Programming knowledge in Python, C.. doing Java now.

So, where should I probably start? and How long it takes me to get into ML, SVM etc.. and be productive? Would I probably fit for this project? --considering my programming background (I so far have been much into Web development, wanted to take a change and have fun)

Comment: This question has been closed for at least two reasons. 1) The goal seems to be to program stuff. [SO] may be more appropriate for what you need to do the actual programming. 2) Your questions can not be answered reliably, as we don't know you, your skills, the project (owner), etc. And if one were to write something that helps you, it is likely to help nobody else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything that should stop you. A couple of tips to set you on the right path:

- The basic principles of Machine Learning are very simple. They are often formalized in a way that makes it look very complicated, but this is only necessary if you want to get into the details of why things work. The general framework of what makes a classifier or what makes a clustering algorithm is very simple. Make sure you understand things on that level, before you dig into the details.
- The title question (can SVMs be understood without ML knowledge) is slightly non-sensical. Understanding the basic ideas of ML is a minor investment and understanding SMVs takes much longer. There's no reason not to get a basic idea of what machine learning is before you dig into SVMs.
- Make sure you have a good intuitive undertanding of the following principles and distinctions: features and instances, clustering and classification, supervised and unsupervised learning. After that, SVMs are just one particular way of solving a particular problem.
- If you understand what a classifier is, you can start using SVMs without knowing anything about how they work or what they do. This may not give you the best result, but it's a good way to start learning by doing.

I can't really give you any references to start reading, since most of what's out there is far to formal for the level you'd want to start with. I recommend browsing around. If something is easy to read, then continue on, if it's too full of math, try something else first.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but you must know what linear programming is ... dual and primal ... also you must be good with using quadratic programming , and if want to understand the application of SVM then you must know Machine learning ... SVM is a binary classifier that separates linear data ... you can use it to separate nonlinear data by using kernel function which transforms the data to linear one,you have other sort of SVM which allow the classifier to make "mistakes" with in some parameters called the slacks,this method maximize what called the "margin": it is twice the distances of the support vector from the separating hyper plane, and it solves , for more information you can use google or [SVM](http://www.cs.haifa.ac.il/~rita/ml_course/lectures_old/SVM.pdf)